# Galaxy Note 4 KitKat 4.4.4 - want to perm sort mail so that unread is on top

Tags: email, filter

I just got this phone and love it. But I'd like the default mail client to allow "UNREAD" on top and then the read ones below. I have to constantly change that each time I check mail. My previous version would only change that if I shut off the phone.

I can't find anything that allows me to default FILTER BY to be UNREAD. Annoying!